# How to get the post thumbnail with global post ID

Tags: wordpress

I have two different post types where I want to have a relationship. Authors can list one business(post type - "listings") and many special offers (post type - "special_offers"). In each single special offer page, I need to display which business offers that specific offer. Currently I'm using this code, and it outputs the Business name correctly. I need the business logo to be there as well (featured image)

```
function get_author_business() {
global $authordata, $post;

$authors_posts = get_posts( array( 'author' => $authordata->ID, 'post_type' => 'listings', 'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ), 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );

foreach ( $authors_posts as $authors_post ) {
    $output .= '<a href="' . get_permalink( $authors_post->ID ) . '">' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $authors_post->post_title, $authors_post->ID ) . '</a>';
}

return $output;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help (i'm assuming you are trying to get the image tag inside your output html)

```
function get_author_business() {
global $authordata, $post;

$authors_posts = get_posts( array( 'author' => $authordata->ID, 'post_type' => 'listings', 'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ), 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );

foreach ( $authors_posts as $authors_post ) {
    $business_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $authors_post->ID ), 'thumbnail' );
    $output .= '<img src="'.$business_img[0].'"><a href="' . get_permalink( $authors_post->ID ) . '">' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $authors_post->post_title, $authors_post->ID ) . '</a>';
}

return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code :

```
<?php 

$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
$attachment_url=wp_get_attachment_image_src($post_thumbnail_id,'full');  
/* full -- is image size */
?>
<img src="<?php echo $attachment_url; ?>">
```

hope that will work for you.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, but this doesn't work inside above method's loop. any idea how get this as an `$output` with `$authors_post->ID` ?